# How to restrict accessing other child forms when a particular child form is active?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my MDI form application, there is a `Browse` button in the parent form. When this button clicked it shows the saved record of currently activated form.
My requirement is when `Browse` form opens other child forms should not be accessible until the `Browse` form does not close.
I tried using `BrowseForm.ShowDialog();` instead of `BrowseForm.Show();` But it's throwing the following exception.

> Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog

Comment: If that's an option don't set an [`MdiParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a browse form and don't add it to the [`MdiChildren`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren(v=vs.110).aspx) of the parent form. Then this exception will go away and you'll be able to display it as a modal dialog.

Comment: @defaultlocale but I want to open browse form inside the application.

Comment: Hmm, is there any particular reason for that? I mean, browse form will block the rest of the application anyway, it makes sense to make it a dialog.

Comment: Actually many codes already have been done on the basis of browse form as a child.

Comment: I see. Then you'll need to do something more complicated: block/disable all other MDI children and/or steal their focus. Check out this article on Code Project: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48436/MDI-child-as-dialog-form-MDI-modal-workaround

Comment: I have an application which is developed in vb6. I found it's possible in that application. So I thought it'll be possible in .net too

Answer (score 0):

To open form as a child thats inside main form use Form.Show();

Else remove if from children of the main form and use form.ShowDialog();